# Raster to Vector, Reduce to Vector - Layer 1: Layer error: must be integral

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to get the centroids of some landsat pixels, but I am getting the error, Layer 1: Layer error: Image.reduceToVectors: First band ('B1') of image must be integral..

Here is my code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/9f65e14d883e8bad6f1e9b4fd0f28915

```
//mean of all data
var l8 = l8.mean().clip(one).select('B1');

//convert to points
var vectors = l8.reduceToVectors({
geometry: above,
crs: l8.projection(),
scale: 30,
geometryType: 'centroid',
maxPixels: 100e9
});


Map.addLayer(vectors);
```

Comment: What's the downvote for?  It's entirely reproducible and EE links are the best way to see the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you go as in GEE playground docs, *reduceToVectors* operates on a image that is "The input image. The first band is expected to be an integer type; adjacent pixels will be in the same segment if they have the same value in this band." This is because it looks for integer labels in the first band. Since you don't have such labels/don't care about them and just need the centroids, you can simply create an integer band and add your B1 band to it

```
l8 = ee.Image.constant(1).clip(one).addBands(l8);
```

but since the default reducer i.e. countEvery operates only on one band as it counts connected pixel, you'll need to define another reducer that uses two bands.

```
var vectors = l8.reduceToVectors({
  reducer:ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: above,
  scale: 30,
  geometryType: 'centroid',
  maxPixels: 100e9
});
```

**OR**
If you don't want to worry about that, you can also just use

```
l8 = ee.Image.constant(1).clip(one);
```

and use the same *reduceToVectors* that you are using right now

**BUT**
This function will give you centroid of each segment of common connected pixels and not the centroid of each pixel that you have not yet masked out. If you want to get centroid of all valid (non masked) pixels within your region then you can instead use the *sample* function using the resolution of image as scale parameter

```
var samplePts = l8.sample({
  region:above,
  scale:30, //scale of image to get centroid of every pixel
  geometries:true
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I just used l8.toInt()